# how to get alexa skill slot value in python

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to get the slot value and access it later but I am not able to get the value. Can you please help me

this is the line i am stuck with. how do i get the response the from slot and save it to the variable.

```
textoutput = intent['slots'].['slotsname'].['value']
```

code:

```
import logging

from random import randint
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session

app = Flask(__name__)
ask = Ask(app, "/")

logging.getLogger("flask_ask").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@ask.intent("MAYBE")

def next_round():
    textoutput = intent['slots'].['slotsname'].['value']
    textoutput1 = 'working'
    textoutput2 = 'not working'
    if textoutput ='ftw':
        schedule_msg4 = render_template('CONNECTION2', schedule4=textoutput1)

    else:
        schedule_msg4 = render_template('CONNECTION2', schedule4=textoutput2)

    return question(schedule_msg4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting elements in Python lists, just use `listName['key']`.
For nested lists use another set of brackets:   `listName['key1']['key2']`.

So do not separate each `[]` with a `.`
So your first line should be:

```
textoutput = intent['slots']['slotKey']['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your `MAYBE` intent to contain a slot named `answer`, a request will look like this. `money` is the value you want to use in your code:

```
"request": {
  "intent": {
    "name": "MAYBE",
    "slots": {
      "answer": {
        "name": "answer",
        "value": "money"
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, you need to adjust your function definition like so:

```
@ask.intent("MAYBE")    
def next_round(answer):    
    textoutput = "You said: {}".format(answer)    
    return statement(textoutput) # "You said: money"
```

Flask-ask will take care of extracting the value from the request.
Check out the [documentation](http://flask-ask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requests.html).